# overloaded method constructor error

Tags: scala, jackson

Using Jackson to deserialize a json to class seems like I need to implement a default constructor without any argument, and also my other constructor put a default value in all attributes

```
class Application(artistViewUrl: String="",
                  trackViewUrl: String="",
                  price: String="",
                  artworkUrl100: String=""
                 ) extends AppleBase {
  def this() {
    this("")
  }

}
```

Without the default values I have the error

```
Error:(14, 5) overloaded method constructor Application with alternatives:
  ()appleSearch.model.app.Application <and>
  (artistViewUrl: String,trackViewUrl: String,price: String,artworkUrl100: String)appleSearch.model.app.Application
 cannot be applied to (String)
    this("")
```

And if I remove the non arguments constructor, Jackson throw this exception

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of politrons.apple.search.model.music.Album: no suitable constructor found, can not deserialize from Object value (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?)
 at [Source: java.io.StringReader@6aba2b86; line: 1, column: 3] (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0])
```

Any idea why?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem. You have two constructors: with 0 and with 4 arguments (no defaults). Then you try to apply one of them to an empty string. Of course they don't fit, because you don't have a constructor that just takes one string. And with defaults you just call the 4-args constructor setting the first one to `""`.

Comment: What happens if you remove the `def this()` constructor, does it compile?

Comment: @pedrofurla jackson throw an exception,  check my update

Answer (score 2):

The type-checker cannot infer the correct constructor to call. By only specifying one argument, none of the constructors will match. You either need to specify all arguments: `this("", "", "", "")`, or use default arguments, as in your example.

Comment: But any idea why Jackson force me to create a default constructor with no arguments?

Comment: Jackson isn't smart enough to be able to use custom constructors. It needs to instantiate a class through the default constructor and then probably uses reflection to set all the fields. That's the way most Java frameworks work.